# Execute free text MySQL command in SSIS

Tags: mysql, ssis

Running Visual Studio 2015 data tools
I know how to create a MS SQL task to run a bunch of SQL DDL and DML queries in one SQL execute task, but how do I do the same for My SQL?

I created a data flow task with a ADO.NET source but I only seem to be able to do one command at a time?

Tried with a Go:

```
create table ab (
id int 
);
go;
insert into table a values (1);
```

I have a combo of 700 lines of DML and DDL to run.

Answer (score 1):

Reading a separate article on [MySQL delimiters](https://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2008/02/most-misunderstood-character-in-mysqls.html), it seems you might be mixing the use of two delimiters.  In using';' as the default delimiter then remove 'GO'.  In using 'GO' as a specified delimiter then remove ';'.